# GeoExplorer not display the associated table to a layer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geoexplorer

GeoExplorer shows the table information associated with a layer of two ways:

1. Information button: clicking on the map is displayed a tab corresponding to the polygon attributes where you click.
2. Query Button: The table shows the data for the entire map.

In the project that we are developing, we start with a shapefile,  manipulate it in QGIS and layers are exported in shapefiles, then uploaded onto GeoServer.

A few months ago we uploaded to GeoServer a set of maps and now we are creating new maps. The old maps being displayed on the GeoExplorer show well the tab and the table, but in the new ones neither the tab nor the table are working, only the table header displays.

Apparently the generation process in both steps the layers was the same. What can be causing this problem?